# What is the %d value of char?

Tags: c

Can someone explain the result of this? Please explain step by step clearly. Thanks a lot.

Why it's -16, -6, - 22? How compiler got these value?

Here's the code:

```
int main(void)
{
    char i=240, j=250, sum;
    sum = i+j;
    printf("Result is: %d + %d = %d\n",i,j,sum);

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the result: Result is: -16 + -6 = -22

Comment: Char is 8 bits. Take the result % 256, check if the high bit is set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
char i=240
```

Overflow. `char` = 8 bits. When signed, it ranges from -128 to 127.
So this converts it to negative.

Suggestion: read your compiler's warnings carefully.

Comment: How the compiler got the -16? thx.

Comment: unsigned 255 = signed -1. unsigned 254 = signed -2, etc.

Comment: There is no overflow, just implementation-specified conversion

Comment: That answer would confuse him. Sometimes it's best to oversimplify things.

Answer (score 1):

Because **Char is 8 bits** and **it's capacity is 255**

> When you add i+j you put ‭**490‬** in sum

Then sum variable **overflow** and it generate negative number

Use `int` instead of `char` **for sum variable** it will solve your problem

Read https://www.cquestions.com/2011/02/char-overflow-in-c.html for more information

Comment: Thanks. But how compiler got these value? any formula?

Comment: @田睿霖 Just count if your number is 254 then your char variable will be 254-256=-2 or if your number is 253 then char variable will be 253-256 = -3

Comment: @田睿霖 i add link to my answer you can read it and you will understand why

Comment: "sum variable overflow " --> No. -16 + -6 --> -22. No overflow in the addition nor assignment to `sum`.